# How can I sort this list by date?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem to sort my list by date.

Here is the code.

```
a = ['28/09 Fenerbahçe Başakşehir FK : 3.0 Normal', '29/09 Samsunspor Gaziantep FK : 2.25 Normal', '30/09 Sivasspor Hatayspor : 2.33 Normal', '30/09 İstanbulspor Antalyaspor : 2.17 Alt Degerli', '30/09 Trabzonspor Pendikspor : 2.67 Normal', '30/09 Galatasaray MKE Ankaragücü : 3.8 Normal', '01/10 Fatih Karagümrük Kasımpaşa : 1.8 Alt Degerli', '01/10 Fenerbahçe Çaykur Rizespor : 3.8 Normal', '01/10 Adana Demirspor Alanyaspor : 2.8 Normal', '01/10 Konyaspor Beşiktaş : 2.83 Normal', '29/09 Hoffenheim Borussia Dortmund : 3.75 Normal', '30/09 Bochum Mönchengladbach : 4.5 Normal', '30/09 Heidenheim Union Berlin : 4.75 Normal', '30/09 Köln Stuttgart : 4.25 Normal', '30/09 Mainz 05 Bayer Leverkusen : 3.25 Normal', '30/09 Wolfsburg Eintracht Frankfurt : 2.25 Alt Degerli', '30/09 RB Leipzig Bayern Münih : 4.0 Normal', '01/10 Darmstadt 98 Werder Bremen : 4.5 Normal', '01/10 Freiburg Augsburg : 3.5 Normal', '28/09 Frosinone Fiorentina : 4.0 Normal', '28/09 Monza Bologna : 1.5 Normal', '28/09 Genoa Roma : 3.5 UST Degerli', '30/09 Lecce Napoli : 2.33 Normal', '30/09 Milan Lazio : 3.2 UST Degerli', '30/09 Salernitana Inter : 2.0 Alt Degerli', '01/10 Bologna Empoli : 2.8 Normal', '01/10 Udinese Genoa : 1.33 Normal', '01/10 Atalanta Juventus : 3.2 Normal', '01/10 Roma Frosinone : 3.2 Normal', '28/09 Celta Vigo Deportivo Alaves : 1.33 Normal', '28/09 Granada Real Betis : 4.5 UST Degerli', '28/09 Osasuna Atletico Madrid : 2.5 UST Degerli', '29/09 Barcelona Sevilla : 3.8 Normal', '30/09 Getafe Villarreal : 2.17 Normal', '30/09 Rayo Vallecano Mallorca : 3.86 UST Degerli', '30/09 Girona Real Madrid : 3.29 Normal', '30/09 Real Sociedad Athletic Bilbao : 3.29 UST Degerli', '01/10 Almeria Granada : 4.0 Normal', '01/10 Deportivo Alaves Osasuna : 3.33 UST Degerli', '30/09 Aston Villa Brighton & Hove Albion : 4.25 Normal', '30/09 Bournemouth Arsenal : 1.2 Alt Degerli', '30/09 Everton Luton Town : 2.0 Normal', '30/09 Manchester United Crystal Palace : 2.83 Normal', '30/09 Newcastle United Burnley : 3.0 Normal', '30/09 West Ham United Sheffield United : 3.5 Normal', '30/09 Wolverhampton Manchester City : 3.8 Normal', '30/09 Tottenham Liverpool : 2.8 Normal', '01/10 Nottingham Forest Brentford : 2.25 Normal', '02/10 Fulham Chelsea : 2.0 Normal']

def get_first_5_chars(item):
    return item[:5]

sorted_data = sorted(a, key=get_first_5_chars)
 
for item in sorted_data:
    print(item)
```

Results:

```
01/10 Fatih Karagümrük Kasımpaşa : 1.8 Alt Degerli
01/10 Fenerbahçe Çaykur Rizespor : 3.8 Normal
01/10 Adana Demirspor Alanyaspor : 2.8 Normal
01/10 Konyaspor Beşiktaş : 2.83 Normal
01/10 Darmstadt 98 Werder Bremen : 4.5 Normal
01/10 Freiburg Augsburg : 3.5 Normal
01/10 Bologna Empoli : 2.8 Normal
01/10 Udinese Genoa : 1.33 Normal
01/10 Atalanta Juventus : 3.2 Normal
01/10 Roma Frosinone : 3.2 Normal
01/10 Almeria Granada : 4.0 Normal
01/10 Deportivo Alaves Osasuna : 3.33 UST Degerli
01/10 Nottingham Forest Brentford : 2.25 Normal
02/10 Fulham Chelsea : 2.0 Normal
28/09 Fenerbahçe Başakşehir FK : 3.0 Normal
28/09 Frosinone Fiorentina : 4.0 Normal
28/09 Monza Bologna : 1.5 Normal
28/09 Genoa Roma : 3.5 UST Degerli
28/09 Celta Vigo Deportivo Alaves : 1.33 Normal
28/09 Granada Real Betis : 4.5 UST Degerli
28/09 Osasuna Atletico Madrid : 2.5 UST Degerli
29/09 Samsunspor Gaziantep FK : 2.25 Normal
29/09 Hoffenheim Borussia Dortmund : 3.75 Normal
29/09 Barcelona Sevilla : 3.8 Normal
30/09 Sivasspor Hatayspor : 2.33 Normal
30/09 İstanbulspor Antalyaspor : 2.17 Alt Degerli
30/09 Trabzonspor Pendikspor : 2.67 Normal
30/09 Galatasaray MKE Ankaragücü : 3.8 Normal
30/09 Bochum Mönchengladbach : 4.5 Normal
30/09 Heidenheim Union Berlin : 4.75 Normal
30/09 Köln Stuttgart : 4.25 Normal
30/09 Mainz 05 Bayer Leverkusen : 3.25 Normal
30/09 Wolfsburg Eintracht Frankfurt : 2.25 Alt Degerli
30/09 RB Leipzig Bayern Münih : 4.0 Normal
30/09 Lecce Napoli : 2.33 Normal
30/09 Milan Lazio : 3.2 UST Degerli
30/09 Salernitana Inter : 2.0 Alt Degerli
30/09 Getafe Villarreal : 2.17 Normal
30/09 Rayo Vallecano Mallorca : 3.86 UST Degerli
30/09 Girona Real Madrid : 3.29 Normal
30/09 Real Sociedad Athletic Bilbao : 3.29 UST Degerli
30/09 Aston Villa Brighton & Hove Albion : 4.25 Normal
30/09 Bournemouth Arsenal : 1.2 Alt Degerli
30/09 Everton Luton Town : 2.0 Normal
30/09 Manchester United Crystal Palace : 2.83 Normal
30/09 Newcastle United Burnley : 3.0 Normal
30/09 West Ham United Sheffield United : 3.5 Normal
30/09 Wolverhampton Manchester City : 3.8 Normal
30/09 Tottenham Liverpool : 2.8 Normal
```

As you see there is a problem on the sorted list.
For example, 01/10 is on the top and 30/09 is at the bottom.
I want a sorted list by the dates.

Thanks very much

What i tried:
I found a code in ChatGPT and used it in the code and did not worked.

```
def get_first_5_chars(item):
    return item[:5]

sorted_data = sorted(a, key=get_first_5_chars)
 
for item in sorted_data:
    print(item)
```

Comment: Your question is wrong, if you want to sort it by date then 02/10 should be at number 1 and 01/10 should be second.

Comment: @bhargav3vedi Why?

Comment: @KellyBundy, because you want to sort it out based on dates. if you sort it based on dates in reverse order then order will be 02/10, 01/10, 30/09 and if you want to sort it by values then order would be 01/10 (110), 02/10 (210), 28/09 (2809) . you mentioned that you want to sort it by date.

Comment: @bhargav3vedi These dates are in DD/MM format and not the MM/DD format used in some locales. If they were MM/DD then the natural (lexical) sort would work

Comment: @DarkKnight, can you please let me know the right sort for given dates? 01/10 (1 October), 02/10 (2 October), 30/09 (30 Sept). if you sort it by dates then order will be 02/10 -> 01/10 -> 30/09

Comment: @bhargav3vedi Why do you insist on reverse? Nobody asked for that.

Comment: @KellyBundy Suh man. You mentioned that you want to sort the data based on date, So I wanted to know that how would you sort data based on the date? is it reverse or ascending order? Your question is not clear.

Comment: @bhargav3vedi If they wanted reverse, they wouldn't complain about October coming before September.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is to sort first by month, then day, and the remainder. That means, we need to split the line into these 3 components:

```py
def month_day_text(text):
    date, remainder = text.split(" ", 1)
    day, month = date.split("/")
    return month, day, remainder

sorted_data = sorted(a, key=month_day_text)
```

Comment: Why by remainder?

Comment: Returning the "remainder" ensures that the teams are ordered within date

Comment: @DarkKnight Sure, but why do that?

Comment: Wow what a solution. it worked.

Comment: Why by remainder? Because that is what I guess the OP would want.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to convert the string to a datetime, like this:

```
import datetime
def get_first_5_chars(item):
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(item[:5], "%d/%m")
```

Comment: it worked :) Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

You just get the date part, but the first item is the day, so you have to split those and sort by month first, then by day.

```
def get_date(item):
    day, month = get_first_5_chars(item).split("/")
    return int(month), int(day)

sorted_data = sorted(a, key=get_date)
```

(Converting to `int` is not strictly necessary here since one-digit numbers have a leading zero, so they would compare correctly as strings, too.)

Comment: Thanks very much. I use VScode and i got this error:
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Comment: @MECRAYAVCIN You probably changed your existing `get_first_5_chars` method, not define a new `get_date` method.

Comment: Thanks very much. It was my misteke :(
Code works like a charm.
As you said i made a mistake. 
If i had 15 reputations, I would have voted this post.
Thanks again.